# Can a website read out my MAC address using JavaScript even though I use Tor?

Tags: security, deanonymization, javascript

If I use a Tor to visit a site with enabled JavaScript, can this website find out my MAC address, monitor serial number, the serial number of the processor etc?

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible. This question was previously discussed at StackOverflow (see [MAC addresses in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385/391761)). Only if you are able to use signed JavaScript it is possible to get more privileges than normal.